# Two ListViews with singleChoice but only one selected at a time

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Trying to implement the following: Two ListViews next to each other with choice mode `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` but only one of the ListViews can have a selected element at a time. So if an element is selected in one ListView, the selected element (if available) of the other ListView should be deselected.

However every time I programmatically uncheck the selected item of the other ListView, **the current ListView also looses the selected item**. Clicking on items shows the hover/active state but none are permanently selected.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="#f00"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="#f00"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        final ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        final ListView list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        adapter1.addAll("Test 1", "Test 2");

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        adapter2.addAll("Test 3", "Test 4");

        list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        list2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
                // problem
                deselect(list2);
            }
        });

        list2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
                // problem
                deselect(list1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void deselect(final ListView list) {
        list.clearChoices();
        list.requestLayout();

        // doesn't work either
        //list.setItemChecked(list.getSelectedItemPosition(), false);
    }
}
```

If I comment out calls to `deselect()` then each ListView on its own works as expected, keeping a single selected item. But that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

I had to implement a custom [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) which returns custom Views implementing [Checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html). Apparently `ListView` only restores selected/checked items properly when they implement `Checkable`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to eliminate the onItemClickListener

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#f00"
        android:onClick="clickListened"/>
```

then:

```
public void clickListened(View view){
     deselect(list2);
    }
```

Hopefully that will work.

Comment: It's not possible to add a clickListener to an AdapterView: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead`